# How to set XML file to RelativeLayout in other file?

Tags: android

So, I have an XML file with a RelativeLayout as the root. Can I set this file to a RelativeLayout (not the root) in another file?

Comment: Kinda sounds like you're looking for the [`include`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag.

Comment: Can this be implemented in Java?

Comment: Why in Java? It's implemented through xml (`include/merge`). But yes, you can `inflate` a layout programmatically.

Comment: Please include that in a answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trought:

```
<include layout="@layout/theFirstRelativeLayout />
```